# Spotify 'show inspector' not working

Tags: spotify

I keep getting an error saying "please select the app you want to inspect".

I know I can only do this with local apps - I'm doing it with the tutorial as just got started with Spotify, which should be fine.

Things I have already tried:

1. Right clicking on the app first and then picking 'show inspector'from top menu.
2. Selecting the app and using short cut ctrl+alt+j
3. Restarting and reinstalling Spotify

I also noticed that I'm getting the same kind of error when I want to re-load the app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the option in the context menu when right-clicked?